# Mouseout and time hide div popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

Would anyone be able to help with suggesting the code needed to add to this solution which I have used to create a popup? [W3 Tutorial on creating a popup div](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp)

I want to use this on repeating table entries, but all the popups stay open when they are clicked. I'd like them to disappear when the mouse leaves the popup, or after a certain time (say 2 seconds) if the mouse doesn't actually go over it. OR, for it to hide other popups when another one is clicked.

I'm going back to this solution I have tried and adapted some other solutions, which work on a test page, but don't when applied to my main php looping page - as there must be some conflicting code which  need more time to identify. However, this pop up example does actually appear.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
/* Popup container */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}
/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {
opacity: 0;
}
to {
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
from {
opacity: 0;
}
to {
opacity:1;
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table style="margin-top: 50px;margin-left: 50px;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(1)">Click me! <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">Popup text...</span> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(2)">Click me! <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Popup text...</span> </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function myFunction(id) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup"+id);
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it will be easy if you show  your code

Comment: Great - thanks. Sorry, I was pushed for time...hopefully you can see it all now. I've just put examples of the rows, but the tables I'm using should use PHP to loop through 10-20 records.

Answer (score 1):

1) I have used Jquery `hide()` and `show()` functions.
2) I have written as an inline style `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`.
3) I have set a `timeout` to hide text after 2 sec.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
/* Popup container */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup .popuptext {
    /* visibility: hidden; */
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}
/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {
opacity: 0;
}
to {
opacity: 1;
}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
from {
opacity: 0;
}
to {
opacity:1;
}
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table style="margin-top: 50px;margin-left: 50px;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(1)">Click me! <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1" style="display: none;">Popup text...</span> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(2)">Click me! <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2" style="display: none;">Popup text...</span> </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function myFunction(id) {
$("#myPopup"+id).show();
  setTimeout(function(){
      $("#myPopup"+id).hide();
}, 2000);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond - I tried it out and it works! Awesome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    /* Popup container */
    .popup {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* The actual popup (appears on top) */
    .popup .popuptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 160px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 8px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -80px;
    }
    /* Popup arrow */
    .popup .popuptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    /* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
    .popup .show {
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
        animation: fadeIn 1s
    }

    /* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
    opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
    opacity: 1;
    }
    }
    @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
    opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
    opacity:1;
    }
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table style="margin-top: 50px;margin-left: 50px;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
      <tr>
        <td><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(1)" onmouseout="myFunction2(1)">Click me! <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">Popup text...</span> </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(2)" onmouseout="myFunction2(2)">Click me! <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Popup text...</span> </div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
    // When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
    function myFunction(id) {
      var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup"+id);
      popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }

 function myFunction2(id) {
      var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup"+id);
      popup.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sometimes you can't see the wood through the trees...but the solution totally makes sense. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your tagged the question with jQuery I will provide an answer using it. But first you need to change your html little bit.

You can wrap "Click me!" with a span to make it receive click events. We can use jQuery data() function to add a timer that is triggered after 2 seconds if `mouseover` did not occur. Using `data()` will attach the timer to the clicked element only.

I have also commented the code to understand the process.

See this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".link").on("click", function() {
    let popup = jQuery(this).siblings('.popuptext');
    popup.toggleClass("show");
  
  // Check the current staet of the link span
    if (popup.hasClass("show")) {
   // Set timout if the popup is shown to remove it in two seconds
      const popupTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        popup.removeClass("show");
      }, 2000);
      popup.data("timeout", popupTimeout)
    } else {
  
   // Clear popup timeout if the popup is hidden
      clearTimeout(popup.data("timeout"));
    }
  });
 
 // If use hovers over the poup then clear timeout and keep the popup
  jQuery(".popup").on("mouseenter", ".popuptext.show", function() {
    let popupText = jQuery(this);
    let timeout = popupText.data("timeout");
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  });
 
 // if user moves mouse away we hide the poup
  jQuery(".popup").on("mouseleave", ".popuptext.show", function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass("show");

  });
});
```

```css
/* Popup container */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="margin-top: 50px;margin-left: 50px;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="popup">
        <span class='link'>Click me!</span>
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1">
     <a href="Link 1">Link 1</a> | <a href="link2">Link 2</a>
    </span> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="popup">
        <span class='link'>Click me!</span>
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">Popup text...</span> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great response! I've put it into my code and it works really well! The only snag I now get is when I add the links to the pop up. If I change the popup span to become: <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup1"><a href="Link 1">Link 1</a> | <a href="link2">Link 2</a></span> </div> it throws out the timeout and hiding. Is it becasue there is now an extra element inside the parent container? Is it an easy fix? –

Comment: You can change the mouseover to mouseenter and mouseout to mousleave. I updated the code